# Is it safe to rely on "use_count()" to re-use "shared_ptr" memory in a multithreaded app?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, shared-ptr

I'm reviewing some old code and I have doubt about the reliability of this one. Unfortunately, the original developer is no longer around so I can't ask him for an explanation.

The following class is in charge of allocating memory on demand for an `struct` than is used in multiple places and from multiple threads. The `getStruct()` is called from one place and one thread only, but the returned `std::shared_ptr<SomeHeavyStruct>` is dispatched to multiple threads. As an optimization, an attempt is made to try to re-use previously created `struct` instead of throwing away old ones.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

struct SomeHeavyStruct
{};

class HeavyStructProvider
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<SomeHeavyStruct> getStruct()
    {
        auto it =
            std::find_if(m_buffer.cbegin(), m_buffer.cend(), [&](const auto& pointer) {
                return pointer.use_count() == 1;
            });

        if (it != m_buffer.cend()) {
            auto pointer = *it;
            return pointer;
        }

        auto newStruct = std::make_shared<SomeHeavyStruct>();
        m_buffer.push_back(newStruct);
        return newStruct;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeHeavyStruct>> m_buffer;
};
```

My concern is that while reading the [`std::shared_ptr<T>::use_count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count) documentation, I'm seeing the following:

> In multithreaded environment, the value returned by use_count is approximate (typical implementations use a `memory_order_relaxed` load)

And also:

> If use_count returns 1, there are no other owners. [...] In multithreaded environment, this does not imply that the object is safe to modify because accesses to the managed object by former shared owners may not have completed, and because new shared owners may be introduced concurrently, such as by std::weak_ptr::lock.

Knowing that the `std::shared_ptr<SomeHeavyStruct>` is used from multiple threads, **am I right to assume the current implementation is prone to unexpected behavior?**

If I had to refactor this code, what would be a suggested approach? Is using a custom `Deleter` protected by a `mutex` the way to go (to effectively mark re-usable struct with a custom flag instead of relying on `use_count()`)?

Comment: Race condition - after the above code reads `use_count` another thread may increase the the count before the  above code now mistakenly thinks it is the sole owner. I think you need a `std::mutex` round any access to `m_buffer`.

Comment: This is not necessarily unsafe. Comparing to `1` is listed as a common use case on the page you linked. Find out: 1) Are there places that take the shared pointer and access the contents after discarding the ownership (which is unsafe by itself) 2) Is this class ever used with `weak_ptr`?

Comment: @RichardCritten Sorry if it wasn't clear enough, but `HeavyStructProvider` and `getStruct()` are only called from one thread, so I suppose it's safe and there is no possible race condition (because if `use_count` returns `1` (modulo the "approximation" mentioned in the docs), then `HeavyStructProvider` is effectively the sole owner of the `shared_ptr` in `m_buffers` and the refcounter can't be incremented by anyone else as there is no other reference).

Comment: @VLL I agree but  it's also mentioned that "In multithreaded environment, the value returned by use_count is approximate" so I'm not sure I can rely on it. They also mentions "accesses to the managed object by former shared owners may not have completed" which I don't know the meaning exactly.

Comment: I think this is OK, it's certainly not the best way to implement an object pool using `shared_ptr`. You can use a custom deleter which puts the object back into the pool when its no longer being used

Comment: @Delgan Does your code look like this? `SomeClass& ref = getStruct()->someClass;  f(someClass);` In this example, the caller is no longer shared owner when `f()` is called.

Comment: If the return value is approximate, it can be either too large or too small. Is there any case in which it would be too small (for example, 1 when it should be 2), if you ensure other places keep the ownership while they are using the pointer? No. If `getStruct()` is called only in one thread, after other places have discarded their references, only `getStruct()` can create new ones.

Comment: @VLL Thanks for the concrete examples. Nothing like that is done, so I guess it's kind of safe.

Comment: If you are in a position to use C++20, there is a specialization of std::atomic to handle shared_ptr in a thread-safe manner. More details at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2

On older versions, there are some deprecated functions that are similar: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic