# Is it safe to rely on "use_count()" to re-use "shared_ptr" memory in a in case the producer is a single thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, shared-ptr

This is a bit similar to this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71466547/is-it-safe-to-rely-on-use-count-to-re-use-shared-ptr-memory-in-a-multithre), but slightly more specific.

In my app, I have a single producer thread that produces objects for other threads to consume. It is safe to assume that this thread is the only one creating those objects.

I would like to be able to reuse such an object once all other consumer threads are done using it.

Initially I thought that if the producer will hold all the created objects, it can reuse them if their reference count is 1. But it seems that `std::shared_ptr<T>::use_count` might not be reliable enough to determine that as it is using weak memory access (Why?).

I have a test application and I notice that sometimes `use_count` might still return > 1 even though other consumers are done with the object (or it might be a software bug on my end).

Questions:

- Does relying on `use_count` being equal 1 is a safe approach in this scenario?
- If it is not safe, why?
- What are some better alternatives for this use case?

Comment: Yep `use_count` is safe and accurate in a single threaded environment.

Comment: That former question at least provides code, care to share a [mcve] extracted from yours? Also, there is one very specific question raised in the original question, namely the use of `std::weak_ptr`, which don't address. Generally, do use RAII idioms to return instances to the pool, but do so explicitly. You might be able to pull it off with a custom deleter for the `shared_ptr`, which would be safe.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe. `use_count` is a very problematic function and can only be used as a rough approximation. The standard notes in [[util.smartptr.shared.obs] `shared_ptr::use_count`](https://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.obs#lib:shared_ptr,use_count):

> When multiple threads might affect the return value of `use_count()`, the result is approximate.
> In particular, `use_count() == 1` does not imply that accesses through a previously destroyed `shared_ptr` have in any sense completed.

These issues are caused by the lack of synchronization. In practice, the issue is:

> The removal of the "debug only" restriction for `use_count` and `unique` in `shared_ptr` introduced a bug: in order for `unique` to produce a useful and reliable value, it needs a synchronize clause to ensure that prior accesses through another reference are visible to the successful caller of `unique`. Many current implementations use a relaxed load, and do not provide this guarantee, since it’s not stated in the Standard. For debug/hint usage that was OK. Without it the specification is unclear and misleading.

- [P0521: Proposed Resolution for CA 14 (`shared_ptr` `use_count`/`unique`)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0521r0.html)

*Note: There used to be a `unique()` function which returned `use_count() == 1`, and it was removed for being misleading.*

You are affected by these problems, and even though only one thread produces new `std::shared_ptr` objects, the lack of synchronization would prevent you from claiming unique ownership with certainty.

#### What are better alternatives?

In your case, only one thread actually produces `std::shared_ptr` objects and increases the reference count.
You also make it sound like that thread performs some post-processing, and therefore never terminates before the others.

This sounds like that thread actually has unique ownership, and could be using `std::unique_ptr` instead. All other threads could be given a non-owning raw pointer.
To keep track of how many threads have access to the pointer, you could use an atomic counter, like a `std::atomic_int` which is incremented/decremented (with `std::memory_order::acq_rel`) when threads are started/joined.

You may also use a [`std::latch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/latch) or some other counting mechanism to keep track of how many threads have given up their reference to the pointed-to object. Once all threads fall through the latch, only one thread will access it.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason why `use_count()` should not be relied upon is that the information it gives you is already outdated once you get around to check it.
(and even if it reports `1` that doesn't imply that it can't change asynchronously)

---

Those are the two primary edge-cases that make `use_count()` effectively useless when more than one thread is involved:

###### 1. `std::weak_pointer<T>` is a thing

Consider two threads, one with a `std::shared_ptr<T>` to your object and one with a `std::weak_ptr<T>` to that same object:

```cpp
// thread 1
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr = /* ... */;
// ...
long count = ptr.use_count();
if(count == 1)
    reuse(ptr);
```

```cpp
// thread 2
std::weak_ptr<T> wptr = /* ... */;
// ...
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr = wptr.lock();
if(ptr)
    fiddle(ptr);
```

Those could be interleaved like this:

| Thread 1 | Thread 2 |
| --- | --- |
| `long count = ptr.use_count();` (count will be 1) |  |
|  | `std::shared_ptr<T> ptr = wptr.lock();` (will be successful) |
| `if(count == 1) reuse(ptr);` (true, calls reuse) |  |
|  | `if(ptr) fiddle(ptr);` (true, calls fiddle) |

... and then you end up with thread 1 attempting to reuse your object thinking it has the only strong reference while thread 2 fiddles with it using a newly created strong reference.

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/W19a3ssMT)

###### 2. the last `std::shared_ptr<T>` instance could be shared

If the last `std::shared_ptr<T>` instance is shared between two threads you can also get a race condition:

```cpp
// global variable
static std::shared_ptr<T> gptr = /* ... */
```

```cpp
// thread 1
long count = gptr.use_count();
if(count == 1)
  reuse(gptr);
```

```cpp
// thread 2
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr = gptr;
fiddle(ptr);
```

Those could be interleaved like this:

| Thread 1 | Thread 2 |
| --- | --- |
| `long count = ptr.use_count();` (count will be 1) |  |
|  | `std::shared_ptr<T> ptr = gptr;` (creates a second strong reference) |
| `if(count == 1) reuse(gptr);` (true, calls reuse) |  |
|  | `fiddle(ptr);` (calls fiddle) |

... which again would result in both `reuse` and `fiddle` being called for the same object on different threads.

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/rrG5abzjd)

---

#### Answers to your questions

- > Does relying on use_count being equal 1 is a safe approach in this scenario?
  > If it is not safe, why?

  It is only safe if:

  - you check for `use_count() == 1`
  - you are certain that no weak pointers exist to that value
  - you are certain that the last remaining `std::shared_ptr<T>` can only ever be accessed by the thread that did the `use_count()` check
- > What are some better alternatives for this use case?

  Use either a custom deleter on your `std::shared_ptr`,
  or (if you can use C++ versions above C++11, specifically C++20) implement a destroying delete dealloaction function for your type. ([`operator delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) - see (27) - (30))

  Note that with both options you shouldn't use `std::make_shared`, because that will allocate the control block alongside your object, which you want to avoid if you want to reuse it later.
- > as it is using weak memory access (Why?)

  Even if it were are strong memory access the result wouldn't be reliable.
  After `use_count()` returns any other thread might e.g. lock a `std::weak_ptr` and therefore alter the reference count.

  So the only cases where the value of `use_count()` can be meaningfully used is when it returns 1 AND the last `std::shared_ptr` instance is not shared between threads AND there are no `std::weak_ptr`s in play.
  And in that case it doesn't matter if the load in `use_count()` gets reordered, since there can only be 1 thread anyway.

Comment: Even if `use_count() == 1`, that does not mean it is safe to to treat the pointer as if you had unique ownership. The reference count gets modified using relaxed atomic operations, so a large number of accesses to the pointed-to object could be ordered *after* the decrement which sets the reference count to one, even if in your code, it looks like you're accessing the pointer first, and then your `std::shared_ptr` goes out of scope. It only becomes safe when you add extra synchronization like a `std::mutex` or `std::latch`, etc.

Comment: @JanSchultke that is why i added two extra conditions (no weak pointers, shared_ptr instance is not shared) - without them you're correct that `use_count() == 1` does not imply unique ownership. Note that decrementing the reference count **must** prevent instructions being reordered past the decrement, otherwise shared_ptr would be completely useless in multithreaded scenarios - typically `std::memory_order::acq_rel` is used ([libcxx](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__memory/shared_ptr.h#L117))

Comment: As pointed out in [P0521](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0521r0.html), some implementations use relaxed ordering. Maybe this has changed now, but I'm not sure about that. And no, relaxed ordering is perfectly reasonable. It would not make `std::shared_ptr` useless for multi-threading. Incrementing and decrementing is a RMW operation, and relaxed ordering is often enough for RMW operations because you read (and modify) the most recent value. With relaxed ordering, the requirements you have listed are not enough to ensure safety.

Comment: @JanSchultke relaxed is okay for incrementing, but never for decrementing. You need release semantics to prevent instructions accessing the pointed-to object from being reordered past the decrement (all modifications to the pointer-to object must be visible to other threads) and acquire semantics for that case that the refcount drops to 0, so that the object destructor can observe all changes that happened to the object from other threads. - the acq_rel is needed for synchronizing instructions before and after the decrement (the rmw itself is of course atomic regardless of the memory order)

Comment: Great, so I think you understand why it's not safe to rely on `use_count()`, even given the conditions you've stated. Note that `relaxed` doesn't allow reordering anything on the same thread in the standard sense; you're still limited to the as-if rule and causality. It's just that other threads may observe a reordering of the increment/decrement and other memory operations. That still doesn't make relaxed useless, since when another thread decrements the reference count and sees zero, they can be sure that the object can be destroyed. That's why some implementations presumably choose relaxed.

Comment: Hmm, I've talked it through with a couple of people and I see now why the decrement must be at least acquire/release. Only the increment can be relaxed.

Answer (score 0):

`use_count` is not reliable in a multithreaded scenario, it is not atomic.  It's genuinely super unreliable. If it's absolutely necessary that the ref count is 1 before reusing, look into std::atomic shared pointers, or some sort of mutex functionality specifically for checking ref count.

Comment: `use_count()` is an atomic load. The issue is that it's an atomic load with relaxed memory ordering, and therefore the result cannot be relied upon, since this load may be reordered arbitrarily.

Comment: Thank you. I can't comment your answer, but it is superior and should be accepted. Unique pointers are an excellent suggestion, but wouldn't passing around a non-owning raw pointer be problematic in other ways? I'm making assumptions about the underlying code but if it is required that all consumers are done, I'm assuming they are using the underlying data and non-owning pointers might be just as problematic as not waiting for a shared_ptr refcount to be 1. If the atomic counter functionality is what makes it work, wouldn't shared_ptr just be more memory safe with the exact same result?

Comment: The problem is that `std::shared_ptr` uses relaxed memory ordering for its counter, and you also don't access it using RMW operations. As a result, you get a possibly out-of-date, and arbitrarily reordered counter, which is not useful. In this case, it is better to make your own counter with at least acquire/release ordering, so that you can be sure that when the counter hits `1`, no accesses to the pointed-to object are ordered afterwards, and you truly have unique ownership.